# Can you import a vhdl package in a systemverilog file?

Tags: vhdl, system-verilog

Can you import a vhdl package in a systemverilog file?

Let's say I have a VHDL package:

```vhdl
    library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

    -- FILE: my_pkg.vhd
    package my_pkg is

      type type1 is record
        sig2 : std_logic;
        vec1 : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
      end record;  

    end package;
```

Can I use it in a System Verilog file like this:

```
// FILE: testbench.sv
import my_pkg::*;

module testbench;

type1 sigtype1;

initial begin
    sigtype1.sig2 = 1'b1;
    sigtype1.vec1 = 8'hA;
    $finish(2);
end

endmodule
```

would this generate a syntax error or would it imply the equivalent systemverilog package:

```
    // FILE: my_pkg.sv
    package my_pkg;

      typedef struct packed {
        bit       sig2;
        bit [7:0] vec1;
      };

    endpackage;
```

Here's my simulator output:

```
C:\questasim64_2020.4\win64\vcom.exe -2002 -l simout.vhdl.log 
-work work ./hdl/my_pkg.vhd
QuestaSim-64 vcom 2020.4 Compiler 2020.10 Oct 13 2020
Start time: 11:39:52 on Jan 19,2022
vcom -2002 -l simout.vhdl.log -work work ./hdl/my_pkg.vhd
-- Loading package STANDARD
-- Loading package TEXTIO
-- Loading package std_logic_1164
-- Compiling package my_pkg
End time: 11:39:52 on Jan 19,2022, Elapsed time: 0:00:00
Errors: 0, Warnings: 0
ok

C:\questasim64_2020.4\win64\vlog.exe -work work -l simout.vlog.log 
./hdl/testbench.sv

QuestaSim-64 vlog 2020.4 Compiler 2020.10 Oct 13 2020

Start time: 11:39:52 on Jan 19,2022

vlog -work work -l simout.vlog.log ./hdl/testbench.sv

** Error: 
C:/Users/wpmoore/Desktop/collins/sandbox/sandbox.try1/hdl/testbench.sv(
2): (vlog-13006) Could not find the package (my_pkg).  Design read will 
continue, but expect a cascade of errors after this failure.  
Furthermore if you experience a vopt-7 error immediately before this 
error then please check the package names or the library search paths 
on the command line.
End time: 11:39:52 on Jan 19,2022, Elapsed time: 0:00:00

Errors: 1, Warnings: 0
```

Comment: I didn't try it... I would curious if it works for all simulators supporting mixed systemverilog and vhdl simulation... mentor, cadence, synopsys, etc...

Comment: how to interface systemverilog to vhdl core that includes an io that is a record type?

Comment: You ask your tool vendor if it is supported, and ask them how to do it. In a previous life, using cadence incisive, records from VHDL to SV was only supported if the VHDL record only contained std_logic/slv or integer fields. Nested records were also not allowed. It would have to be a struct in SV. There is no standard definition of how the two languages talk to each other. The best part about incisive was that with nested records it would compile fine, but the interface just got corrupted during simulation.

Answer (score 2):

I am only aware of one tool, Modelsim/Questa that allows sharing of packages  between SystemVerilog and VHDL, and only for the sharing of data types/typedefs across these languages. The most useful purpose being connecting ports between mixed language instances with a shared data type.

Look for the `-mixedsvvh` switch in the Questa User Manual.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer 'No'.

If you can get your simulator to compile a VHDL module you may well be able to instantiate it in a Verilog / SV module, and vice versa.  Although you are mixing languages here it is fairly unambiguous how the simulator should connect these.  However because they are different languages it is not defined how code written in both should interact with each other.  Certainly I would not expect any VHDL packages to be usable in Verilog/SV.  Can you migrate the contents to SV?  Or perhaps create a tool to generate two files equivalent VHDL and SV?

Comment: actually it appears to work if you convert VHDL record types to systemverilog packed structs...  which leads me to believe that a vhdl entity instantiated in systemverilog will convert a record type into a packed array of bits when interfacing to verilog...  you are probably right... that what is needed is a script to convert the VHDL package into a systemverilog package with structs that are packed...